# Creating reverse relationship objects with Model Mommy

Tags: python, django, model-mommy

I use Model Mommy for creating test data and it's working fine so far.

Now I have a Django model named `Invoice` and a related model named `InvoiceItem`.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(users.User)

class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, related_name='items')
```

I've created two simple Mommy recipes for these models:

```
InvoiceRecipe = Recipe(
    Invoice,
    created_by=foreign_key(UserRecipe),
)

InvoiceItemRecipe = Recipe(
    InvoiceItem,
    invoice=foreign_key(InvoiceRecipe),
)
```

Now I'd like `InvoiceRecipe.make()` to automatically add a varying number of `InvoiceItem` objects to the invoice that is created.

Currently, I'm doing it like this, but I'd like it to automatically happen:

```
invoice = InvoiceRecipe.make(created_by=contractor)
invoice.items.add(InvoiceItemRecipe.make())
invoice.items.add(InvoiceItemRecipe.make())
```

Comment: Do you mean a varying number as in a random number, or a specified number? Something like: `invoice.items.add(InvoiceItemRecipe.make(), _quantity=3)` for example?

Comment: @DanielHolmes: Either one works for my use case to be honest, but ideally it'd be an arbitrary number between n and m :)

Comment: I don't think model mommy has such functionality. One thing you could do is to create your own `Recipe` class which which would inherit from model mommy, but that may be more effort than for what it's worth...

Comment: one could use the `related` inside the [Recipe](https://model-bakery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#recipes-with-foreign-keys) definition to populate reverse related objects.